# How to update the datagrid after updating a selected value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, sql-update

The Below code is updating the record but not reflecting it inside the Datagrid. What should I add to the update function to reflect the changes instantly after the update message?

**Xaml Code**

```
 <Button Command="{Binding CmdUpdateUser}" Content="Update User"/>
```

**ViewModel File**

```
         private void UpdateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE Customer " +
                    $"SET Id='{Id}',Name='{Name.ToString()}'," +
                    $"Age='{Age}',Country='{Country.ToString()}'," +
                    $"Active='{Convert.ToBoolean(Active)}'" +
                    $" WHERE Id='{Convert.ToInt32(SelectedCustomer.id)}'",con);
                int n=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (n > 0)
                {                   
                    MessageBox.Show("Update Successful");                 
                }
                Customer current = customer.Where(x => x.id == SelectedCustomer.id).FirstOrDefault();
                current.id =Id;
                current.name =Name;
                current.age = Age;
                current.country = Country;
                current.active = Active;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Customer` class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) and raise change notifications in the setters of the `Id`, `Name`, `Age`, `Country` and `Active` properties:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //+ the same for the rest of the properties

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}
```

Comment: public class ViewModelPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChange(string PropertyName)
        {
            var Handler = PropertyChanged;
            if(Handler!=null)
            {
                Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }
    } I have used the INotifyPropertyChangeEvent

Comment: I don't understand why you put code in a comment. How is this related to the code in your question? Also, you haven't posted your `DataGrid`.

Comment: I am sorry I new to putting questions to StackOverflow so it got a little messed up. And as for the question , the issue is solved. OnPropertyChange Event Call was missing. So thank you for your answer.It helped to solve the issue.